# Is $\psi (x_1,...,x_n)=\det \begin {pmatrix} x^1_1 & \dots &x^1_n \\ \vdots & &\vdots \\ x^n_1 & \dots & x^n_n\end{pmatrix}$ multilinear?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Suppose $\forall x_1,\ldots,x_n,\in R^n$, denote $x_1=(x_1^1,x_1^2,\ldots,x_1^n),x_2=(x_2^1,\ldots,x^n_2)$. Define $\psi:V\times V\times \dots\times V\to R$ as follows: $$\psi (x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\det \begin {pmatrix} x^1_1 & \dots &x^1_n \\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ x^n_1 &\dots &x^n_n\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then is $\psi$ multilinear?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think? Have you explored the simpler case of $n = 2$?

Comment: how do you define the determinant?

Comment: Sum over the permutation for entries along the diagonal multiplied by signature,

Comment: I think Tom had good advice, write out what you know for $n=2$. Or, think about $\psi(x_1+cy, \dots , x_n)$ and see if you can simplify it. Then, exploit the symmetry of the determinant in term of column exchange...

Comment: Well, I think exchanging the column yields a minus sign isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean $\psi \colon V^n \to R$.

Yes, $\psi$ is multilinear. This fact is one of the fundamental properties of determinants.

Comment: sure, but, if he has the misfortune of thinking the determinant is defined by the cofactor expansion then there is something for him to prove...

Comment: Yes, the approach taken to prove it will depend on the definition of determinants used.

Comment: exactly, if we used my preference for determinant the multilinearity is manifest in the definition.